# BluetoothSocket accept() IOException

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I do only have this problem with an outgoing connection. I coppied most parts of my sourcecode from the example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Therefore I don´t really know whats the cause of this problem is...

First of all the code where the IOException occures:

```
try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }
```

Every time I connect my phone to my tablet accept() throws an IOException on my phone:

BluetoothChatService Socket Type: nullaccept() failed
BluetoothChatService java.io.IOException: Operation Canceled

I believe this is somehow related to the problem that is described in this blog:
http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/86844.html

By the way the BluetoothConnection works well, but my phone can´t receive any data.

Edit: I have just realized that a bluetooth connection from my Galaxy S to my Motorola Xoom could not be established with other popular bluetooth apps from the market...

If I connect the other way round, from my tablet to my phone, the tablet just reboots completely.

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace so we can see what is happening. Maybe one end is closing the connection prematurely

Answer (score 0):

It could be an authentication issue. Are your devices paired?

Comment: Yes. They are paired or so it says in the preferences.